# "Decrease on" or "Decrease"

Tags: single-word-requests

Below sentence comes from VOA, I don't understand why she says "decrease on that." Can I say "decrease that"? I have never seen "decrease on."

> I saw on the news and social media that that there was a blood shortage everywhere. And I've been a donor in the past and know that my blood is particularly valuable, I have O negative blood. And so, I've really felt this was a time for me to come out. We have quite a dedicated mobile donor base. However, we have had to **decrease on that**.

Comment: This sounds like an on-air interview. She is trying to say, in the words that puzzle you, “we had to decrease the number of times we went to give blood”, Why is that so hard to figure out?

Comment: @Xanne - Actually, the words were spoken by two different people.  Starting with "We have", the speaker is one of the technicians collecting blood, and there are words prior to that explaining that blood collection activity has been greatly shut down by COVID.

Comment: @Abc1997 - You shouldn't have edited out so much of the intervening dialog.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/voiceofamerica/videos/214810143267618/

Comment: Thanks @HotLicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decrease may take a prepositional phrase complement when used as a noun, but never as a verb. The verb form may be either intransitive or mono-transitive.

noun + *on*

> Property owners within these special service areas will see a **decrease on** their property taxes because the interest rate on the bank loan is lower than the average interest rate of roughly 4 percent that village previously charged those taxpayers. (Chicago Tribune 16-09-12)

verb (intransitive)

> This past fall, enrollment in Virginia public schools dropped for the
>   first time since 1984 as birth rates **decrease**. (Virginian-Pilot
>   19-02-03)

verb (transitive)

> Thus, if you're using milk, you can **decrease the likelihood** of
>   curdling by stirring in 2 tablespoons of potato starch dissolved in an
>   ounce or two of water. (Chicago Tribune 19-04-28)

So, to answer your question, when using *decrease* as a transitive verb, we may say *decrease **that***. In the text given, *decrease* is used as a verb and hence the *on* following it is likely a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

We have quite a dedicated mobile donor base.However, we have had to decrease on that."

The decrease is most likely *on* the mobile base. They have had to decrease the amount of, or the dedication of, or the activity of the mobile donor base. It does not sound quite like correct English. It is an example of someone writing out what someone is saying. And what they are saying is not as careful as it might be. They might have said, "We have had to *restrict* that." or "We have had to *discontinue* that." Your suggestion of *decrease that* is quite correct.